# onPostExecute in AsyncTask inside Retrofit is fired too early

Tags: android, android-asynctask, retrofit

I'm trying to upload multiple images to the server and sending them one by one through Asynctask. Once the image is uploaded, I save the url to a local list and send it for processing in onPostExecute. But, I'm having problems since the onPostExecute is firing too early and doInBackground only returns a null list.

Passing the URIs to the Asynctask

```
new UploadImages().execute(arrayUri);
```

My Asynctask

```
private class UploadImages extends AsyncTask<Uri,Void,List<String>>{

        @Override
        protected List<String> doInBackground(Uri... params) {
            final ArrayList<String> urlList = new ArrayList<>();

            for(Uri uri : params) {
                File file = new File(uri.getPath());
                RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
                MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.getName(), requestBody);
                RequestBody folderName = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), folder);

                ApiEndpointInterface apiEndpointInterface = RetrofitManager.getApiInterface();

                Call<FileInfo> call4File = apiEndpointInterface.postFile(body, folderName);

                call4File.enqueue(new ApiCallback<FileInfo>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void do4Failure(Throwable t) {
                        Log.d(TAG, t.toString());
                        snackbar = Snackbar.make(newIncidentLayout, R.string.sb_image_upload_error, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        snackbar.show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void do4PositiveResponse(Response<FileInfo> response) {
                        FileInfo fileDetails = response.body();
                        urlList.add(fileDetails.getImage());
                        Log.d(TAG, "Uploaded Image");
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void do4NegativeResponse(Response<FileInfo> response) {
                        String bodyMsg = "";
                        try {
                            bodyMsg = new String(response.errorBody().bytes());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Log.d(TAG, bodyMsg);
                        snackbar = Snackbar.make(newIncidentLayout, R.string.sb_image_upload_error, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        snackbar.show();
                    }
                });
            }
            return urlList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<String> urlList) {
            super.onPostExecute(urlList);

            //Post Incident
            setProgressMessage("Posting incident...");
            //other code here
        }
    }
```

I've tried adding a thread.sleep but the outcomes are never the same. Sometimes I get a list in return, other times nothing happens.

I'm not sure why this is happening. I hope you can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Whenever you `enqueue()` something with a callback object argument, that's a good sign that it's already an asynchronous operation. That is, you don't need the `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In android, retrofit calls are made in a background thread by default. You shouldn't/don't need to use `AsyncTask`.

You can write the code for `onPostExecute` inside the method `onResponse` (or in your case `do4PositiveResponse` and `do4NegativeResponse`) of your retrofit callback.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of calls synchronous and asynchronous. You are using enqueue which is asynchronous so u dont need to use async task. Just remove async task from your code and use remaining of your code will do the job so instead of whole code above use following:

```
ArrayList<String> urlList = new ArrayList<>();

            for(Uri uri : params) {
                File file = new File(uri.getPath());
                RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
                MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.getName(), requestBody);
                RequestBody folderName = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), folder);

                ApiEndpointInterface apiEndpointInterface = RetrofitManager.getApiInterface();

                Call<FileInfo> call4File = apiEndpointInterface.postFile(body, folderName);

                call4File.enqueue(new ApiCallback<FileInfo>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void do4Failure(Throwable t) {
                        Log.d(TAG, t.toString());
                        snackbar = Snackbar.make(newIncidentLayout, R.string.sb_image_upload_error, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        snackbar.show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void do4PositiveResponse(Response<FileInfo> response) {
                        FileInfo fileDetails = response.body();
                        urlList.add(fileDetails.getImage());
                        Log.d(TAG, "Uploaded Image");
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void do4NegativeResponse(Response<FileInfo> response) {
                        String bodyMsg = "";
                        try {
                            bodyMsg = new String(response.errorBody().bytes());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Log.d(TAG, bodyMsg);
                        snackbar = Snackbar.make(newIncidentLayout, R.string.sb_image_upload_error, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        snackbar.show();
                    }
                });
            }
```

After that what you are doing in onPostExecute do it after the completion of for loop.

Comment: It will work for you. Also if it works do let me know and mark my post as an answer to your question. It will give me reputation buddy :)